# get value of child from parent

Tags: xslt

From parent node, i need to test the value of one of the child's in order to generate the adequate output.

my XML file looks  :

```
 <Tables>
    <Table>
      <Multi_entity>SPECIFIC</Multi_entity>
      <Table_name>CATEG</Table_name>
      <Is_temporary>FALSE</Is_temporary>
      <Tablespace>APSYS_LOCATION_1</Tablespace>
      <Column>
        <Column_name>CATEGI</Column_name>
        <Position>1</Position>
        <Type>Small</Type>
        <Size>22</Size>
        <Null>No</Null>
        <Default>Yes</Default>
        <Attribute>Precision=5</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Scale=0</Attribute>
      </Column>
      <Column>
        <Column_name>CATEGC</Column_name>
        <Position>2</Position>
        <Type>LongVarchar</Type>
        <Size>1</Size>
        <Null>No</Null>
        <Default>Yes</Default>
        <Attribute>Precision=0</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Scale=0</Attribute>
      </Column>
      <Column>
        <Column_name>CATEG_NAME</Column_name>
        <Position>3</Position>
        <Type>Varchar</Type>
        <Size>23</Size>
        <Null>No</Null>
        <Default>Yes</Default>
        <Attribute>Precision=0</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Scale=0</Attribute>
      </Column>
      <Column>
        <Column_name>CATEG_TYPE</Column_name>
        <Position>4</Position>
        <Type>Small</Type>
        <Size>22</Size>
        <Null>No</Null>
        <Default>Yes</Default>
        <Attribute>Precision=5</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Scale=0</Attribute>
      </Column>
    </Table>
```

from the "Table" node, i need to know if one of the "Column" has a "Type" value "LongVarchar".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does

```
<xsl:template match="Table[Column/Type = 'LongVarchar']">
  <!-- now transform or output as neeed -->
</xsl:template>
```

help? That matches any `Table` having a `Column` with `Type` being that value `LongVarchar`.

Comment: thank you, but can we have another command that can be used with <xsl:when test= ...>

Comment: @SamiBOB: The solution provided by Martin is superior to using `xsl:choose`. It is much better -- maintainable, extensible and in the spirit of XSLT to use templates and pattern matching vs. explicit conditional logic in a single, monolithic and non-reusable template.

Comment: SamiBOB, I fully agree with Dimitre that using pattern matching and apply-templates is the proper XSLT approach and that you should aim to implement that approach. If you really think however you need to use `xsl:when` then the code does not need change, you can use an expression evaluating to a node set in an `xsl:when test` and that condition is true if the node set is not empty and false if the node set is empty.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  : that's what i'm asking for , how can i write this kind of expression? because this is the only way that works in my case :-)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come along my problem in a way that is so easy that i am really astonished about it's simplicity :

```
<xsl:when test="Column/Type='LongVarchar'">
```

that's it and it works perfectly. 
Thanks folks for all your Help.